# Flask CORS not attaching correct headers when server starts, after waiting ~5 minutes it attaches the correct headers

Tags: reactjs, flask, cors

I am utilizing Flask CORS in order to add response headers.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
# CORS enabled so react frontend can pull data from flask backend
CORS(app)


@app.route('/plot1', methods=["GET"])
def plot1(): 

    # Implementation hidden
    
    channel = request.args.get('channel', default='Channel1')

    return send_file("bokeh_plot.png", mimetype='image/png')
```

When I first start the Flask server and make a request from Axios using:

```
const params = {
  channel: selectedOption,
};

Axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/plot1", { 
  params: params, 
  responseType: 'blob'
}).then(response => 
{
  let imageNode = document.getElementById('image');
  let imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
  imageNode.src = imgUrl;
});
```

The response errors with:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/plot1?channel=Channel1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

After waiting a short time, around 5 minutes, the requests function as normal and the correct headers are attached by Flask CORS. I've reinstalled Flask and Flask CORS, attempted to append headers myself to the response, utilized non-wildcard CORS implementation, and a handful of other solutions. I appreciate any help that anyone can provide.